# vb.net escape reserved keywords in sql statement

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to execute an sql statement in vb.net to an Access database, I am escaping the reserverd word using square brackets []. This has worked in all my `SELECT` statements within the program.

The reserved word is `level`

But the SQL statement below fails saying

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

If I directly copy the statement and execute this in Access it works fine

```
datalayer.getDataTable(String.Format("INSERT INTO users (username, password, [level]) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2})", username, password, level))
```

The above statement works if I remove [level] and replace this with another column name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not enclosing your values in quotation marks.  Try this:

```
datalayer.getDataTable(String.Format(
 "INSERT INTO users (username, password, [level]) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')", 
 username, password, level))
```

However, as Andrew says, you should really use parameters.  In Access SQL *(David W Fenton will come along shortly and say it's "Jet" SQL)* you have to use positional parameters.  Your statement would then look like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, [level]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

You'd need to create OleDbParameter objects with the correct values, and an OleDbCommand with the text above to execute in order to do your insert.

Comment: I have tried quoting the values, but this still has the same outcome? Thanks.

Comment: @Elliott, edit your answer and show us the exact statements you're executing in Access.  Both the one with [level] that doesn't work, and the one with something else that does work.

Answer (score 0):

Always use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx). What you're doing is very dangerous and leaves the door open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Then you won't have to worry about escaping the values you're inserting into the database.

Comment: Hi, as this project is for college I dont have to worry about secuirty issues, is there a quick fix for this? Thanks

Comment: Not really - by using parameters you get improved security and remove the need for escaping the data.

Comment: I would tend to worry about secuirty but i'm in a rush to finish this project, but I guess I will look into it. Thanks :)

Comment: I'd look into it even regardless of the security enhancements. It's just a faster, cleaner way to generate query text.