# How to save address of a person which is having (, ; ') etc into access database via VB.Net Form

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

How to save address of a person which is having `(, ; ')` etc into access database table via VB.Net?

as Access DBMS consider these characters `(,;')` as SQL Statements...

Comment: I’m sure it doesn’t. Access can handle strings just fine. I’m sure your code is broken and you’re not using parameters as you should. But since there’s no code shown we can’t help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434669/vb-net-escape-reserved-keywords-in-sql-statement

Comment: If you cannot store strings with those characters in them that means you are vulnerable to [**SQL Injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You've got to use a parameterized query to filter your input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create parameterized queries in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851341/how-to-create-parameterized-queries-in-vb-net)

Comment: Please show what you have tried to achieve this, then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

"Unfortunately, MS Access doesn't support typical operators that are traditionally used during SQL injection testing..."

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_MS_Access